# SQLite Database selecting MAX(column) on two columns, while also selecting a Distinct value from a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I'm attempting to Select information from an SQLite Database I created (something similar to this):

```
  Date      Time    Acc  TotalAcc  Proc  TotalProc
21-12-01 | 00:00 |  133 |     133 |  76 |       76 
21-12-01 | 01:00 |  270 |     403 | 260 |      336 
21-12-01 | 02:00 |   35 |     438 |  24 |      360
21-12-01 | 02:00 |   50 |     453 |  30 |      366 
21-12-02 | 00:00 |  113 |     113 |  89 |       89
21-12-02 | 07:00 |    2 |    1290 |   6 |     1199 
21-12-02 | 07:00 |   28 |    1316 |  17 |     1210 
21-12-02 | 07:00 |  432 |    1720 | 384 |     1577
21-12-02 | 07:00 |  502 |    2222 | 403 |     1975
```

The information I'm looking to gather: a **unique Date** (only 1 from each day), with the **Max Time** (in this case it would be 07:00 for 21-12-01, and 02:00 for 21-12-02).

**The final metric I want for sorting (this is where I'm having trouble):** I also want to select the row that contains the **highest TotalAcc**.

Currently, this is the SQL logic I'm using to pull data:

example =

```
"SELECT DISTINCT Date, TotalAcc, TotalProc, MAX(Time) 
    FROM table_name 
    GROUP BY Date 
    ORDER BY Date DESC, MAX(Time) DESC"

df = pd.read_sql_query(example, con)
print(df)
```

> ouput

[image: output from print(df)]

The data I'm looking to take from the database should look more like this:

```
          Date TotalAcc  TotalProc  MAX(Time)
0 | 21-12-02 |      453 |      366 | 02:00
1 | 21-12-01 |     2222 |     1975 | 07:00
```

I've tried using MAX(TotalAcc) instead of TotalAcc when selecting the data, but it returns me a number that's different from the actual max value in the column for that given time and date.
Setting example = `'SELECT MAX(TotalAcc) FROM table_name'` returns a non-max value (1290, for example).

I apologize for not giving a total replicable example, I pull my data points from a source, which populates the table I create like this:

```
with con:
                con.execute('''
                    CREATE TABLE table_name (
                        Date TEXT,
                        Time TEXT,
                        Acc TEXT,
                        TotalAcc TEXT,
                        Proc TEXT,
                        TotalProc TEXT
                    );''')
```

Any and all ideas are appreciated, SQL logic seems a bit confusing at times.

Comment: What if the row having the max `Time` is not the same as the row having the max `TotalAcc`?

Comment: With the data I'm using, it shouldn't be possible. I use `df['TotalAcc'] = df.['Acc'].cumsum()` after sorting it by time. I group the data by hour, and I believe the problem occurs where there are multiple data points for 07:00 (due to pulling the data more than once in a given hour, and appending that to the SQLite database.

Comment: Please post desired result or explain why current output does not meet your needs.

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to the original post.

Comment: IIUC - Sounds like you need to `MAX` all non-grouped columns: *TotalAcc*, *TotalProc*, *Time*. In most databases, your attempted SQL should have raised an error!

Comment: @Parfait SQLite, like MySQL, is more tolerant of non ANSI `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, indeed and arguably a disservice to newcomers of SQL!

Comment: The definition of the column `TotalAcc` as `TEXT` most probably will cause you problems. It should be defined as `INTEGER`, otherwise you will get the row with alphabetically max value of `TotalAcc`. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=83c3aea7a1b84cf8180ba0b8d1ec5e63

Comment: @forpas that's good advice, I'll make that change. Thanks for pointing dbfiddle for sqlite, that's looks extremely helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you want a query along these lines:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date
                                 ORDER BY Time DESC, TotalAcc DESC) rn
    FROM table_name
)

SELECT Date, Time, Acc, TotalAcc, Proc, TotalProc
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This will return one row per date, having the max time.  Should two or more rows on the same date also have the same max time, then the row having the highest `TotalProc` will be selected.

Comment: Awesome, that seems to work well for me. I'll have to collect a few more data points across my database to confirm it's perfect, but it definitely answers the question, thank you!